# Percentage sign larger than > does not work for negative percentages

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to return a TRUE or FALSE from an AND statement where it is TRUE if A1 > A2 > A3

```
=AND(A1 > A2 , A2 > A3)
```

A1, A2 and A3 are all percentages. Google sheets recognizes that a larger negative percentage is still larger than a lesser percentage. How do I go about changing this so that:

If A1 is 50%, A2 is -5% and A3 is -50% would return TRUE

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=and(A3 < A2, A2 < A1)`